# Organize files using PowerShell using path as variables?

Tags: powershell

I have a script that reorganizes files in C:\Year\Month\"StoreFiles" to "C:\Store\Date\"StoreFiles" based on modified date.

```
#Variables
$StoreName = "aStore"
$SourceDir = "C:\Source"
$TargetDir = "C:\$StoreName"

# Create Folder based on Store List
if(-Not (Test-Path -Path $TargetDir)) {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $TargetDir
}

# Search & create folders based on date
Get-ChildItem "$SourceDir\*$StoreName*" -Recurse | ForEach-Object { 
    $x = $_.LastWriteTime.ToShortDateString()
    $new_folder_name = Get-Date $x -Format MMM-yyyy
    $des_path = "$TargetDir\$new_folder_name"

    if (Test-Path $des_path) { 
        Copy-Item $_.FullName $des_path 
    } else {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $des_path
        Copy-Item $_.FullName $des_path 
    }
}
```

Works great however the modified date isn't ideal.  Can I use the original folder path of "C:\Year\Month\"StoreFiles" and use it as dates for the new output?

In a sense I am trying to do the following:
"C:\Year\Month\"StoreFiles" to "C:\Store\Month-Year\"StoreFiles"

Maybe I should assign the folder path as a variable and use it accordingly for the new output?

Or is there another way I should think about doing this.

Answer (score 0):

try Something like this

```
$dirroot="C:\temp\Root"
$store="C:\store"

Get-ChildItem $dirroot -file -Recurse | 
    where FullName -match  ([Regex]::Escape($dirroot) + "\\\d{4}\\\d{1,2}\\" + [Regex]::Escape($_.Name)) |
    % {
        $elements=$_.FullName.Replace($dirroot, '').Split('\')
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "$store\$($elements[2])-$($elements[1])" -Force
        Copy-Item $_.FullName "$store\$($elements[2])-$($elements[1])\$($elements[3])"
      }
```

Comment: This might work however I am having a tough time getting it to work.  Example of the folder structure "C:\Test v2\_SOURCE\2016\01-Jan\Bill Payment Stubs\FILES"  I just want to take the 2016 and 01-Jan folder portion.

Answer (score 0):

Cann't you use something like this?

$DateInfo = '' | select-object -Property 'Year', 'Month'

```
$File = 'c:\2014\may\filename.txt'
$TopFolderpath = [io.Path]::GetDirectoryName($File)
$TopFolderName = [io.Path]::GetFileName($TopFolderpath)
$DateInfo.Month = $TopFolderName
$Subfolderpath = [io.Path]::GetDirectoryName($TopFolderpath)
$SubFolderName = [io.Path]::GetFileName($Subfolderpath)
$DateInfo.Year = $SubFolderName

$DateInfo
```

Comment: The problem with that is the date the file was created or modified doesn't' reflect the date it should be in.  Accounting usually adds the invoices a month or two later after to the folder structure.  This means that the folder structure would have the accurate date info.